# Big Muff Pi Black Russian Pots

Tags: potentiometer, specifications

I try to repair a Big Muff Pi Black Russian, which was assembled in 2001. Unfortunately, I don't understand the labeling of a broken pot. See picture below. Since the device was assembled in Russia, I believe the labeling is written in Russian. Does anybody understand from the picture, what replacement part I need to use?

[image: Russian(?) labeling of broke potentiometer]

Comment: what is a *Big Muff Pi Black Russian*?

Comment: and yes, that looks Cyrillic, and without even speaking a word of Russion myself: that's not Russion, that's just letters and numbers; you can just look them up in a table of the Cyrillic alphabet, copy and paste them into google, and hope for the best. Exactly what we or any Russian would do.

Comment: I still want to know what it is but don't want to risk any big muff websites (pie or no pie).

Comment: LOL @Andyaka I believe it's a guitar distortion pedal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is the black colored, russian version of the Big Muff Pi, which is a very famous fuzz pedal for e-guitar. [See here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWfvv0YCVKM) for demo.

Answer (score 5):

- Disconnect at least two of the wires.
- Measure the end to end resistance on the outer tags. That tells you the pot resistance value.
- Turn it to centre position and measure the resistance from the wiper to one end.

  - If the centre-end resistance is half of the track resistance then it's a linear pot.
  - Otherwise it's a logarithmic (audio-taper) pot.

All this assumes that the track and wiper are intact. If not you'll have to wait for the Russians to arrive.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a lick of Russian, but [this site](https://www.ehx.com/forums/viewthread/9857/#42526) seems to indicate you need a 100K linear pot (B taper) with a 1/8" (maybe actually 3mm) shaft.

Most, or all, of this you should be able to confirm by measurement.

Answer (score 1):

*Which* pot is broken (volume, tone, distortion)? Many pedals like this will use multiple pots and they're not always the same value. However...

I was able to find a schematic for the unit. I have *no* idea how accurate it is or if it applies to the unit you have, so proceed with caution. All three pots shown are the same value of 100kΩ linear taper. There's a note that sometimes 150kΩ were used.

[image: Schematic]

*([Source](http://www.bigmuffpage.com/images/schematics/V7_V8_BMP_Schematic_TallFontRussian_BubbleFontRussian.jpg))*

A potentiometer uses this schematic symbol:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdRNf7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Normally repair questions like this are closed as off-topic, because we can't know how much or little experience or knowledge you have designing or repairing electronic devices. But I'm going to look the other way because guitar pedals are a soft spot... That said, there's a lot of mumbo-jumbo in the music/audio communities about certain components having near-magic properties. If you just get a quality replacement of the appropriate value, you will have good results. (Good quality meaning it is well built with smooth wiper action, the linearity of the carbon trace is good, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I found the above schematic by myself before asking the question. And because of that _sometimes_, I actually posted the question.